# If permutation p=(148)(25)(396)(7) how to find p^123?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

If permutation p=(148)(25)(396)(7) how to find p^123 ?

Comment: OK, what have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Is the exponent divisible by 2? 3? Think about each cycle independently.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Your permutation is very conveniently written in disjoint cyclic form.  A very nice property of permutations written as disjoint cycles is that raising the permutation to a power as a whole is equivalent to raising each cycle to that power individually (*seen easily by the fact that disjoint cycles commute with one another and induction*).

> $p^{123} = (148)^{123}(25)^{123}(396)^{123}(7)^{123}$.  Now, consider simplifying each of these cycles individually.